# How to identify web actions in JavaFX webview?

Tags: javascript, webview, javafx

I need to catch the actions like clicks, drag, right-click, double click etc, that are done by the user on JavaFX web view. How to achieve it?

Comment: You must be able to use `setOnMouseClicked()`, `setOnMouseDragged()` methods on the WebView.

Comment: I dont see these methods for webEngine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setOnMouseClicked()`, `setOnMouseDragged()` methods on the WebView.

The following example prints `Mouse Clicked!` in the console for every `Mouse Click` event.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        webView.setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.out.println("Mouse Clicked!"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(webView, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Welcome");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```